# Improve if condition logic

Tags: c#, .net

I want to improve my code logic. I have too many If conditions in the logic. I am wondering if there is a  better way of doing this logic. Here is the code

```
if (item != null && item.Fields != null && item.Fields["WilcardPage"] != null) {
    wildCardItemUrl = item.Fields["WilcardPage"].Value;     
}

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(wildCardItemUrl)) {

    if (item.Children.Count == 1) {
        wildCardItemUrl = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item);
    } else {
        var settings = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(ID.Parse(settingsItem));
        if (settings != null) {
            var wildcardItem = _workContext.SitecoreContext.Cast < SiteSettings > (settings);
            wildCardItemUrl = (wildcardItem.ItemWildcardPage != null) ? MediaReleaseHelper.FixMediaReleaseUrl(wildcardItem.ItemWildcardPage.ItemUrl) : string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The C# 3 tag states: _"Use this tag if your question specifically pertains to C# 3.0 specific features."_ and the C# 9 tag states: _"Use this tag for issues related to development with version 9.0 of the C# language."_. Please can you edit your question to show how these are both relevant (especially considering you can only choose one version at once when you compile your code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, there is not a lot to improve here, but try this:

```
wildCardItemUrl = item?.Fields?["WilcardPage"]?.Value ?? wildCardItemUrl;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(wildCardItemUrl)) {
  if (item?.Children.Count == 1) {
    wildCardItemUrl = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item);
  } else {
    var settings = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(ID.Parse(settingsItem));
    if (settings != null) {
      var wildcardItem = _workContext.SitecoreContext.Cast<SiteSettings> (settings);
      wildCardItemUrl = (wildcardItem.ItemWildcardPage != null) ? MediaReleaseHelper.FixMediaReleaseUrl(wildcardItem.ItemWildcardPage.ItemUrl) : string.Empty;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Another slight improvement would be to invert the string.IsNullOrEmpty to reduce nesting. IE, `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(wildCardItemUrl)) return;` Also the settings != null: `if (settings == null) return;`.

Answer (score 0):

If:

1. `Fields["..."]` never throws and
2. `wildCardItemUrl` is null before the `if`

then you can substitute the if with:

```
wildCardItemUrl = item?.Fields?["WilcardPage"]?.Value;
```